# Keycloak admin not accessible on cluster at non standard port

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm running a keyclock cluster on docker compose at port 8080.

Home page is rendered, but the admin link ignores the port, it is `localhost/admin`.

Docker compose YAML:

```
services:
  kc1:
    container_name: kc1
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    environment:
      KC_DB: oracle
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.0.1:1521/xepdb1?oracle.net.disableOob=true
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:8000/auth
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
    entrypoint: "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev"

  kc2:
    container_name: kc2
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    environment:
      KC_DB: oracle
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.0.1:1521/xepdb1?oracle.net.disableOob=true
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:8000/auth
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: true
    entrypoint: "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev"

  lb:
    container_name: kc_lb
    image: nginx:alpine
    logging:
      driver: none
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - kc1
      - kc2
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream backend {
    server kc1:8080 fail_timeout=5s;
    server kc2:8080 fail_timeout=5s;
}

server {
    listen          8000;
    server_name     localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port        $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
        proxy_pass                                  http://backend;
    }
}
```

It works on port 80 to a point, in this case it fails after authentication.